# Creating a png image from SpriteKit Node/SpriteNode in Xcode for Mac

Tags: image, macos, swift, sprite-kit

Currently I'm making an isometric map editor (in Swift) where each map tile is added to an `SKNode` called `mapLayer`. I want to know whether it is possible to produce a png image from this `mapLayer`, once I have finished designing a map?

Answer (score 1):

Not in Swift but it should give you a good idea on how to do it.

You can capture your screen to a UIImage by doing this:

```
CGRect bounds = self.scene.view.bounds;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage* screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then create a PNG image from the UIImage (and write it to disk) like this:

```
// Create paths to output images
NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"];
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.jpg"];
```

Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625378/how-to-render-a-sknode-to-uiimage).

```
// Write a UIImage to JPEG with minimum compression (best quality)
// The value 'image' must be a UIImage object
// The value '1.0' represents image compression quality as value from 0.0 to 1.0
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

// Write image to PNG
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];

// Let's check to see if files were successfully written...

// Create file manager
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Point to Document directory
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

// Write out the contents of home directory to console
NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
```

Source [here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/save-uiimage-object-as-a-png-or-jpeg-file.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to write the contents of the view to a PNG file. First, define a UIView extension that captures the contents of the view and converts it to a `UIImage`.

```
extension UIView {
    func screenGrab() -> UIImage {
        // Uncomment this (and comment out the next statement) for retina screen capture
        // UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 1.0)
        drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Then, define a UIImage extension that writes a `UIImage` to a file.

```
extension UIImage {
    func writeToFile(fileName:String) {
        let path = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Documents/"+fileName)
        UIImagePNGRepresentation(self).writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    }
}
```

Lastly, capture and write the contents of the view to a PNG file with

```
self.view?.screenGrab().writeToFile("capture.png")
```

and here's how to determine where the PNGs will be stored:

```
println(NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Documents"))
```

Comment: I take it this would work for iOS since it uses UIKit, but I want it to work for a mac application. Is there an equivalent using AppKit?

Comment: Sorry about that. I missed the osx tag. I'll have to research that.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the instances where macOS and iOS behave very differently. Spoiler: the usual methods of capturing the contents of an NSView to NSImage don't work.

NSImage(data:inside:) and NSView.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in:to) work fine for NSView, but if you embed an SKView or apply them to the SKView directly, you'll only get a blank canvas.

The solution lies in thinking SpriteKit:

An SKScene is an SKNode at heart (actually, an SKEmitterNode), and SKView has a method called texture(from: SKNode) which gives you an SKTexture. SKTexture has a cgImage() property, and there you are.

This assumes three properties in the NSViewController that presents the scene: skView: SKView, scene: SKScene?, and an NSImageView for display named snapView.

```
  if  let rendered = skView.texture(from: scene!){
        snapView.image = NSImage(cgImage: rendered.cgImage(), size: self.skView.bounds.size)
```

(Don't force unwrap, it's only for demo purposes)

Comment: I know: old, downvoted question. This was the first search result for trying to take a screenshot of an SKView on macOS, so I'm posting the answer anyway.